# Reference to an element with a different namespace with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, prefix

I'm constructing a XML schema with `XSLT` using just one specific value from the input schema. My goal is to construct a generic xslt for other documents.

Here is my input `xsd` simplified :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" SCCOAMCD:desc="  implémentation du MCD pivot du SCCOA 3.2.1ec  production par SCCOA mcd2mpd 4.1.1, le 11/12/2007  règles spécifiques production schémas 1.2  diagramme : A-SC.SBE GestionZonesAeriennes SYSCA  entité racine      : A-SC.ZoneAerienne " attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" version="3.2.1ec">

<xsd:element name="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>

<xsd:schema>
```

I writted this `xslt` :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsd xdt err fn"
xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>

<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"
xmlns:xrm="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:metier="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"  targetNamespace="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xsl:call-template name="importbalisesXrm"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="importNamespaceXrm"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:call-template name="mapping"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="mapping">
<xsd:complexType name="mapping">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="{xsd:element/@name}" namespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="occurs"></xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is with this instruction, the output XSD gives me `ref="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"` while i would like `ref="metier:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"`.
Hope someone has an idea to add a `prefix` with the `value-of` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you do this...

```
<xsd:element ref="{xsd:element/@name}" ... />
```

But Attribute Value Templates don't need to take up the whole of the attribute value. You can just do this...

```
<xsd:element ref="metier:{xsd:element/@name}" ... />
```

An alternative would be to do this, but this is not as concise

```
<xsd:element ref="{concat('metier:', xsd:element/@name)}" ... />
```

For future reference, you can use as many AVTs as you want, so this would be valid, for example, although rather excessive

```
 <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="'metier'" />
 <xsd:element ref="{$prefix}:{xsd:element/@name}" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that it was that simple... Should i delete my post?

Comment: It's only simple once you know the answer :). But I think in this case, it may genuinely benefit other newcomers to XSLT, so it is worth keeping the question.

Comment: Definitely keep your question and @TimC's answer for the benefit of future readers.